# Allowing single IP to auth with Flask using HTTPBasicAuth

Tags: python, authentication, flask, ip, authorization

Today I set up my flask site to use https://flask-httpauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ although I would like to make it that only single IP can be logged with certain login and password, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get the ip address and check if someone has logged in from it.

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST']):
def login():
    ip = request.remote_addr
    # Check the ip address and the user credentials
```

Comment: Thank's for anwsering. As you stated with session expiring is there a way to check wether client is connected to the site? I mean the site that I'm using is a map which is constantly updating so there must be a way to do it

Comment: @Michał I think that one of the ways is to keep a record of loggin in and remove record when user logs out. Look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44671975/how-can-i-limit-the-session-in-flask/44674754#44674754 I have recently answered similar question. Hope this helps.